# row index retrieval for a php array column

Tags: php, arrays

Can we get the row **index of a column** in a 2 dimensional php array. I need to get the index of row as it was in the php array.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Also show the array.

Comment: how are you currently accessing the data? Loop? Post it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//Demo Array
$ARRAY = arrauy(
    "0" => array(
        "col1"=>"",
        "col2"=>"",
        "col3"=>"",
        "col4"=>"",
        "col5"=>"",
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "col1"=>"",
        "col2"=>"",
        "col3"=>"",
        "col4"=>"",
        "col5"=>"",
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "col1"=>"",
        "col2"=>"",
        "col3"=>"",
        "col4"=>"",
        "col5"=>"",
    ),
    "3" => array(
        "col1"=>"",
        "col2"=>"",
        "col3"=>"",
        "col4"=>"",
        "col5"=>"",
    ),
    "4" => array(
        "col1"=>"",
        "col2"=>"",
        "col3"=>"",
        "col4"=>"",
        "col5"=>"",
    ),
);

foreach($ARRAY as $rowkey=>$rowval)
{
    foreach($rowval as $colkey=>$colval)
    {
        echo($rowkey);
    }
}

?>
```